# Failed to retrieve price Id for external disk for particular (osl) datacenter

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We have a python script to attach external hard disk.
These are the following steps we use to get the price id for particular size
example:10 GB (SAN)

## Retrieve the details of particular datacenter

```
location = client["SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter"].getDatacenters(filter=location_object_filter, mask=location_object_mask)
```

## get the id of data center from the location json

```
location_group_id = location[0]["priceGroups"][0]["id"]
```

## Retrieve all items from package 46

```
items = client["SoftLayer_Product_Package"].getItems(id=46)
```

Here we retrieve the price id of disk in the appropriate location

```
for item in items:
            if item['itemCategory']['categoryCode'] == "guest_disk1" and item['description'] == disk:  
                   for price in item['prices']:
                       if location_group_id == price["locationGroupId"]:
                                   price_id =  price['id']
```

Current issue is that we are not able to get price details for osl datacenter.
But its available for other datacenter.
I tried for ams01, i was able retrieve the price id.
I tried adding external disk from UI of softlayer. It was successful.

Comment: which is the datacenter that failed? I have undertood that the locations prices are only available for datacenters different from Dallas, so if your datacenter is in Dallas your should pick the standard price (the ones which locationGrupuId is null) also if your datacenter is different from Dallas anyway try to use the standard prices that should fix your issue

Comment: It failed for osl datacenter. And also how do i get standard data prices. How do i find them using API Calls?

Comment: read this article http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you